# Eclipse code error marks does not auto-refresh

Tags: eclipse

I am working with Eclipse Photon 4.8.0 and I'm facing a weird behaviour when I'm working with Java files.

When I make a change in a file, usually Eclipse refresh the code reviewer automatically, marking errors and warnings on the fly in the code. This is not happening to me. The code marks appears or disappears only when I save the file.

I suppose there is some preference option to allow auto-refresh for this code checks, but I can't find it.

Comment: Make sure that the 'Project > Build Automatically' menu item is checked.

Comment: Yes, it's checked

Answer (score 1):

In ***Window > Preferences: Java > Editor*** check the checkbox ***Report problems as you type***.

Comment: It was already checked. Uncheck and check seems to have the same behaviour :(

Answer (score 0):

I think that actually it's not a fix for the problem, but I delete this Eclipse and downloaded Eclipse Oxygen. Now it works. I suppose it's a bug for the new Eclipse Photon.

Comment: I'm using Photon (4.8) and I cannot reproduce the issue. Did you have additional plugins installed in Photon?

Comment: Only Spring Tool Suite, I downloaded it one week ago so it's quite a clean installation. I used something like a new Eclipse install wizard.